# How to create Django formset from jquery dynamically form?

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-forms, formset

After user fill a basic form, the data will be showed in table, dynamically created via jquery.

index.html

```html
<form>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
         <label for="sourceip">Source IP:<span> *</span></label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sourceip" placeholder="_._._._ , _._._._ , _._._._" value="" >
         <span class="error_form" id="sourceip_error_message"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
         <label for="destip">Destination IP:<span> *</span></label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="destip" placeholder="_._._._ , _._._._ , _._._._" value="" >
         <span class="error_form" id="destip_error_message"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="service">Service:<span> *</span></label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="service"  placeholder="" >
         <span class="error_form" id="service_error_message"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="comment">Comment: </label>
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="comment"  placeholder="Add comment"> </textarea>
   </div>
   <hr class="mb-4">
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block add" value="Add rule"> 
</form>
<div id="tabulka" class="table col-md-10">
   <form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <!--{{ formset.management_form }}-->
      <table >
         <thead class="thead-dark">
            <th scope="col">Source IP</th>
            <th scope="col">Destination IP</th>
            <th scope="col">Service</th>
            <th scope="col">Comment</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2">Action</th>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="tbody">
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="insert record">
   </form>
</div>
```

script.js

```
$(".add").click(function () {
    var SourceIP = CheckIPAdresses($("#sourceip").val()); 
    var DestIP = CheckIPAdresses($("#destip").val()); 
    var Service = CheckService($("#service").val());
    var Comment = $("#comment").val();

    for (sadd in SourceIP ){
    for (dadd in DestIP){
    for (srv in Service){

    var markup = "<tr class='table-row' > <td class='SourceIP'> <input name='sip' type='text' class='sip' readonly value='"+SourceIP[sadd] + "'>  </td>  <td class='DestIP'> <input type='text' name='dip'  class='dip' readonly value='"+DestIP[dadd] + "'></td><td class='Service'>  <input type='text' class='port' name='port'  readonly value='"+Service[srv] + "'></td><td class='Comment'> <input type='text' class='comm' name='comm' readonly value='"+Comment + "'></td> <td><a class='btn btn-xs delete'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a></td><td><a class='btn btn-xs edit'><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt'></i></a></td></tr>";


    $("#tbody").append(markup);
    $(".table-row").attr('id', function (index) {
        return "rec-" + index;
    });
} } } });
```

views.py

```
def InsertRecord(request):
    form=InsertIPForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return redirect('app')
    context = {"InsertIPForm": InsertIPForm}
    return render(request, "app.html", context)
```

Now I need send data from this table to database. There is no problem  with one record, but when I have multiple record, only last record is saved to database. I use Django and I think that the FORMSET will be the right solution. But I have no idea how to create formset from dynamically created forms.

Could you please help me? Or do you have any other idea how can I do it?

Thank you.